.NET AutoCAD AttachPdf
I am trying to attach PDFs to Autocad via .NET.
Initially the XRef is not visible in the XREF Dialog, after reopening of the drawing the XRef will be shown as "Unreferenced"
Here my code
           public static void AttachPdf(Transaction tr, Database db, string downloadedFileName)
           {
               string strPdfName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(downloadedFileName);
               string strPdfFirstPageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(downloadedFileName) + " - 1";

               DBDictionary dbDict = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(db.NamedObjectsDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
               string pdfDictKey = UnderlayDefinition.GetDictionaryKey(typeof(PdfDefinition));
               if (!dbDict.Contains(pdfDictKey))
               {
                   using (DBDictionary dict = new DBDictionary())
                   {
                       dbDict.UpgradeOpen();
                       dbDict.SetAt(pdfDictKey, dict);
                       tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dict, true);
                   }
               }
               DBDictionary pdfDict = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(dbDict.GetAt(pdfDictKey), OpenMode.ForWrite);
               if (pdfDict.Contains(strPdfFirstPageName))
               {
                   throw new Exception($"image name [{strPdfFirstPageName}] already exists in external references");
               }
               using (PdfDefinition pdfDefNew = new PdfDefinition())
               {
                   pdfDefNew.SourceFileName = downloadedFileName;
                   pdfDefNew.Load(null);
                   var pdfDefId = pdfDict.SetAt(strPdfName, pdfDefNew);
                   pdfDefNew.ItemName = strPdfFirstPageName;
                   tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pdfDefNew, true);
                   using (PdfReference pdfRefNew = new PdfReference())

                   {
                       pdfRefNew.DefinitionId = pdfDefId;
                       pdfRefNew.Rotation = 0;
                       pdfRefNew.Position = new Point3d(0, 0, 0.0);
                       pdfRefNew.NameOfSheet = "1";
                       BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                       BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);
                       btr.AppendEntity(pdfRefNew);
                       tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pdfRefNew, true);
                   }
                   
               }
           }

As reference I already implemented this for Pictures, which does work...
            public static void AttachImage(Transaction tr, Database db, string downloadedFileName)
            {
                string strImgName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(downloadedFileName);

                // Get the image dictionary
                ObjectId acImgDctID = RasterImageDef.GetImageDictionary(db);

                // Check to see if the dictionary does not exist, it not then create it
                if (acImgDctID.IsNull)
                {
                    acImgDctID = RasterImageDef.CreateImageDictionary(db);
                }

                // Open the image dictionary
                DBDictionary acImgDict = tr.GetObject(acImgDctID, OpenMode.ForRead) as DBDictionary;

                // Check to see if the image definition already exists
                if (acImgDict.Contains(strImgName))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"image name [{strImgName}] already exists in external references");
                }

                // Create a raster image definition
                using (RasterImageDef acRasterDefNew = new RasterImageDef())
                {

                    // Set the source for the image file
                    acRasterDefNew.SourceFileName = downloadedFileName;

                    // Load the image into memory
                    acRasterDefNew.Load();

                    // Add the image definition to the dictionary
                    tr.GetObject(acImgDctID, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    var acImgDefId = acImgDict.SetAt(strImgName, acRasterDefNew);

                    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acRasterDefNew, true);

                    // Open the Block table for read
                    BlockTable acBlkTbl;
                    acBlkTbl = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

                    // Open the Block table record Model space for write
                    BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec;
                    acBlkTblRec = tr.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                                    OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

                    // Create the new image and assign it the image definition
                    using (RasterImage acRaster = new RasterImage())
                    {
                        acRaster.ImageDefId = acImgDefId;

                        // Use ImageWidth and ImageHeight to get the size of the image in pixels (1024 x 768).
                        // Use ResolutionMMPerPixel to determine the number of millimeters in a pixel so you 
                        // can convert the size of the drawing into other units or millimeters based on the 
                        // drawing units used in the current drawing.

                        // Define the width and height of the image
                        Vector3d width;
                        Vector3d height;

                        // Check to see if the measurement is set to English (Imperial) or Metric units
                        if (db.Measurement == MeasurementValue.English)
                        {
                            width = new Vector3d((acRasterDefNew.ResolutionMMPerPixel.X * acRaster.ImageWidth) / 25.4, 0, 0);
                            height = new Vector3d(0, (acRasterDefNew.ResolutionMMPerPixel.Y * acRaster.ImageHeight) / 25.4, 0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            width = new Vector3d(acRasterDefNew.ResolutionMMPerPixel.X * acRaster.ImageWidth, 0, 0);
                            height = new Vector3d(0, acRasterDefNew.ResolutionMMPerPixel.Y * acRaster.ImageHeight, 0);
                        }

                        // Define the position for the image 
                        Point3d insPt = new Point3d(5.0, 5.0, 0.0);

                        // Define and assign a coordinate system for the image's orientation
                        CoordinateSystem3d coordinateSystem = new CoordinateSystem3d(insPt, width * 2, height * 2);
                        acRaster.Orientation = coordinateSystem;

                        // Set the rotation angle for the image
                        acRaster.Rotation = 0;

                        // Add the new object to the block table record and the transaction
                        acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acRaster);
                        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acRaster, true);

                        // Connect the raster definition and image together so the definition
                        // does not appear as "unreferenced" in the External References palette.
                        RasterImage.EnableReactors(true);
                        acRaster.AssociateRasterDef(acRasterDefNew);
                    }
                }
            }

My guess is that i have to implement something like:
RasterImage.EnableReactors(true);
acRaster.AssociateRasterDef(acRasterDefNew);
Sadly I could not find anything like this related to pdf
